# Legend hangs with large featurelayers at startup of ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers, legend

My problem is that I created an app with a lot of services that the user can use. The problem is that when I implement the legend widget and the code goes over startup(), the app becomes stuck and it is impossible to do nothing. I start thinking that it is possible that legend is working as synchronous but rest is asynchronous.

This happens with JavaScript API v 3.6 or upper but with 3.4 is working right. (But I want to migrate to 3.10)

Then I can't understand the reason of that stuck.

Comment: Can you either post your code here or use something like [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was a Chile's Layer that it was taking too much time to load (47 sec) and then the legend also was trying to load. The solution was to load the legend after the webpage it was loade with this code:

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
       loadLegendLayers();
   }
```